# Test-driven development vs. Test-first development

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

What is test-first development and how does it corelate to TDD? Is test-first development a general name for things like TDD? If yes, what other test-first practices do exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Test-First Development == Test-Driven
>   Development.

Two different words for the same thing.

Other alternatives to TDD include the increasingly popular [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) (Behaviour Driven Development).

Which method you choose greatly depends both on your application (web, console, windows, etc) as well as your project methodology (Agile, Waterfall, etc).

Comment: If TDD and TFD are the same, is it incorrect to call BDD as test-first development approach?

Comment: No, its not incorrect. I merely said Test-First Development == Test-Driven Development to keep it simple for you, but really:

Test-First Development is an umbrella term for different approaches to testing before coding. Two of these approaches are TDD and BDD.

TFD > (TDD && BDD)

Comment: Okay, that's what I expected. Thank you!

Comment: I generally agree, but it is not true that it depends on the project methodology. TDD is just a programming style, BDD a testing style, which is both completely independent from a software development process.

Comment: @Stefan - agreed, although i have yet to see a Waterfall-style project that uses TDD. Most of these projects use actual test case documents (created in parallel to the actual coding by test analysts). But that's just from my experience (which is < 5 years in this industry), so i could be wrong.

Answer (score 19):

Test First Development is slightly broader, slightly less specific, than TDD.  You can write an acceptance test before coding, then code to make it pass; that's TFD but not TDD.  TDD is more specifically about unit tests - so there is a tighter implied granularity - and includes the red-green-refactor cycle: write your failing (unit) test; demonstrate that it fails; make it pass; demonstrate that it passes; look for opportunities to refactor.  TFD doesn't preclude any of those things, but it also doesn't require them.

Answer (score -3):

TFD is a subclass of TDD.

TDD:
You write a piece of code and you write test for it.

TFD:
You write a test first writing minimal code to make it pass. Then think of the logic and build the code. With this way your code can be well formed and minimal.

TFD can be very helpful sometimes. Instead of jumping into the implementation and test it, you might want to test small pieces of it before writing the whole.

But the purpose of TFD and TDD both are the same.